# Error virtualbox 6.1 al emular cualquier MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, debian, virtualbox

Actualmente utilizo la versión 6.1.18 de virtualbox en debian 10.
La imagen que utilizo es High Sierra aunque también probé con Catalina.

Tengo instalado en virtualbox el pack expansión para poder utilizar, por ejemplo, USB 3.0 entre otras cosas.

En cuento a la configuración de la máquina es:

- 5 procesadores
- Una memoria RAM de 4096 mb
- Chipset PIIX3
- Está quitado el disquete dentro de la orden de arraque
- Una memoria de video de 128 mb
- Controlador gráfico VBoxVGA (3D activado)
- USB 3.0 habilitado

Lo demás está por defecto. Si es necesario lo pongo también.

Adjunto el fichero VBox.log de la máquina a continuación. Esta se inicia pero se congela al poco de arrancar. Muchas gracias.

[VBox.log ANTES de apagar la máquina.](https://pastebin.com/785TQzzs)

[VBox.log DESPUÉS de apagar la máquina](https://pastebin.com/cGvfdRcf).

También ejecuté este código que por lo visto es necesario:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Your-VM-Name" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
VBoxManage setextradata "Your-VM-Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
VBoxManage setextradata "Your-VM-Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "Your-VM-Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"
VBoxManage setextradata "Your-VM-Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
VBoxManage setextradata "Your-VM-Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

Por quitar dudas, cambié "Your-VM-Name" por el nombre de mi VM. En este caso MacOS.

Comment: Yo me tiré cerca de 3h para lo mismo que tú, tuve que configurar muchas variables de entorno en VirtualBox y, cuando lo conseguí, SO iba a 15FPS. Si es por gusto, te diría que dejaras de intentarlo porque no merece la pena. Le di los mismos recursos que tú le estás dando.

Comment: Entonces supongo que lo dejaré estar. Muchas gracias Sergio.

Comment: Por si acaso, la licencia de OSX no permite usarlo por fuera de equipos Mac.